# What is the mean facet.field={!ex=fk3}brands_en_string in solr search query?

Tags: solr

I could not understand **fk3(fk18,fk13....)** in **facet.field={!ex=fk3}brands_en_string** .I referred apache solr doc,here stated **ex** usage with some example .

q=mainquery&fq=status:public&fq={!tag=dt}doctype:pdf&facet=true&facet.field={!ex=dt}doctype

Note : Here created **dt** with **tag** key word, But **fk3** not created any where in my search query.Is work properly?

Query:

q=((inStockFlag_boolean:true)+OR+(ean_string:(men%5E101.0))+OR+(code_string:(men%5E91.0))+OR+(name_text_en:(men%5E100.0+OR+men*%5E50.0+OR+men%7E%5E25.0))+OR+(manufacturerName_text:(men%5E80.0+OR+men*%5E40.0+OR+men%7E%5E20.0))+OR+(keywords_text_en:(men%5E40.0+OR+men*%5E20.0+OR+men%7E%5E10.0))+OR+(searchKeywords_text_en_mv:(men%5E16.0))+OR+(categoryName_text_en_mv:(men%5E20.0+OR+men*%5E10.0+OR+men%7E%5E5.0))+OR+(description_text_en:(men%5E11.0))+OR+(variantSkuList_string_mv:(men%5E91.0))+OR+(styleCode_string:(men%5E6.0))+OR+(boostInventoryWithDCImprovedsearch_boolean:(true%5E50.0)))+AND++NOT+(priceValue_inr_double:0)&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.dictionary=en&spellcheck.collate=true&spellcheck.q=men&fq=(((catalogId:"sslProductCatalog")+AND+(catalogVersion:Online)))&start=0&rows=25&facet=true&facet.field={!ex=fk8}size_en_string&facet.field={!ex=fk18}swatchColors_string_mv&facet.field={!ex=fk12}allPromotions_string_mv&facet.field={!ex=fk14}style_en_string&facet.field={!ex=fk11}price_inr_string&facet.field={!ex=fk13}shopBySize_string_mv&facet.field=categoryPath_string_mv&facet.field={!ex=fk1}giftAgeGroup_string&facet.field=brandAutosuggestRefine_string&facet.field=allCategories_string_mv&facet.field={!ex=fk16}brand_string_mv&facet.field={!ex=fk6}genderAutoSuggestionImprovedSearch_string_mv&facet.field=myallCategories_string_mv&facet.field={!ex=fk7}giftTo_string_mv&facet.field={!ex=fk5}boostInventoryWithDCImprovedsearch_boolean&facet.field={!ex=fk0}occasion_string_mv&facet.field={!ex=fk3}brands_en_string&facet.field={!ex=fk9}genderInBrandsAutoSuggestionImprovedSearch_string_mv&facet.field={!ex=fk15}category_string_mv&sort=score+desc%2CinStockFlag_boolean+desc%2Cscore+desc&facet.mincount=1&facet.limit=500&facet.sort=count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no filter with the tag mentioned in `ex`, it doesn't do anything useful.

The functionality is there to exclude a filter when creating the facet counts, i.e. to get the counts as the filter mentioned in `ex` hasn't been applied.

This is useful for having facets that contain counts for a complete set of documents, even if the user has selected one of the facets:

```
[ ] Cars (329)
[ ] Real estate (42)
[x] Misc (1337)
```